# Loading a file using Model View Controller Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am trying to read a txt file and then use some of the information in that text file in a drop down selector in the View. Though, I am unsure which part of the MVC the loading of the file is supposed to go in, and how I get that information to the drop down.

I was thinking I load the file in the Controller and send the info to the View but am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core idea behind MVC is that you should be able to "slice away" the view and controller and still be able to retain the model portion if you had to change graphical frameworks. Thus, file loading and writing belongs in the model classes. You therefore populate the views and controllers with the data stored in the models.

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> I was thinking I load the file in the Controller and send the info to the View but am unsure.

No, the data read by the file is key data that should be held by the model. The view should only display the state of the model and create a visible framework for interaction with the user. It should not hold the key data. The controller should mediate interactions between the model and view and should handle user interaction with the model.

Myself, I'd have the control request of the model that it load the file then have the information that the file contains sent to the **MODEL** not the view. Then the View would be notified by the model (or the controller) that the model's state has been changed, and would then display the new state of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Loading of a file should go in the Model. The controller in your case should be just for the sake of communication between model and view.